# How to use a variable which is defined in another function but want use in next function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

Here I want to use variable object a again in my next function but when I tried using a in my next function it gave a NameError.
Also I don't want to make variable at beginning of the function, I want to make it in a function also want to use in next function.

CODE

```
def A():
    a=12
    print(a*12)
A()

def B():
    b=14
    print(b*a)
B()
```

OUTPUT

```
  144
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/a.py", line 9, in <module>
  B()
 File "C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/a.py", line 8, in B
  print(b*a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Any Solution would be aprreciated,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like a is a constant, not a variable. Why not define a in the common scope of both functions?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to pass `a` in as a parameter into the `B` function.

```
def A():
    local_a=12
    print(local_a*12)
    return local_a
    # local_a stops existing here, but that's okay because we 
    # have returned the value it contained

outer_a = A() # variable `outer_a` is the value we returned from function `A` (12 in this case)

def B(a):
    b=14
    print(b*a)

B(outer_a) # pass outer_a  into function `B`
```

Comment: Hmm......I Got it. So i was just missing to return and call the variable which i want to use in my next function.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple problem of global variable and local variable, notice when you declare "a" its scope is only inside the function A,rather you can declare "a" outside the function and continue the program as it is,because now the scope of the variable is for the whole program.

```
a = 0
b = 0 
def A():
    a=12
    print(a*12)
    return a
a = A()

def B():
    b=14
    print(b*a)
B()
```

Comment: umm.....you have done a mistake here assigning a=0 and b=0 as it will give the output 0 in function B because the value of will not change i.e. it will be 0 bcoz after executing function A the variable a will not exist as 12 it will exist as a,so the function B will give output 0.you can check if you dont believe me.

Comment: yes,you are correct maybe the best solution is A() function returning a also.

Answer (score -2):

Just declare the variable in the function-scope as global at the beginning

```
def A():
    global a
    a = 12
    print(a*12)
A()

def B():
    b=14
    print(b*a)
B()
```

Output:

```
144
168

Process finished with exit code 0
```

With that being answered, the value of your code is questionable.
As you declare a variable within your functions and return a "arithmetic" version of this variable your function is pretty much useless. Or rather to say, your functions do not fullfill a purpose in a programmatic way, nameley simplify repetitive operations for type-static input.
Calling your A() or B() is literally the same as printing the arithmetics or the integers itself as the output (return) of your functions are pretty much static.

Comment: Global variables are not a replacement for function arguments and return values.

Comment: It is probably better to define a at global scope directly, not requiring the function call to initialise it.

Comment: Yes thanks for the correction. I did not read the question carefully enough!